# When to use @Optional() and ternary operator in typescript Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, annotations, angular

I am bit confused When to use @Optional and When to use ?: 
For @Optional

```
 import {Optional} from '@angular/core';
    log:string;
    constructor(@Optional() private logger:Logger) { 
 }
```

For ternary operator(?:)

```
 export class DataService {
            private videos: string[]

            getAllMovies(fetchFromService?: boolean): ng.IPromise<any> {
                var self = this;

                if (fetchFromService) {
                    return getMoviesFromService();
                } else {
                        return getVideosFromService();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

They are meant for two completely different cases.

The `@Optional()` decorator is meant as an annotation for injecting services with the constructor. Those services are then marked as optional and no exception will be thrown if the service can't be resolved or no provider for it can be found in the hierarchy.

The ternary operator on the other hand marks a method argument as optional. So you actually can omit those arguments which will then default to null like this:

```
getAllMovies(true).then(...)
```

or

```
getAllMovies().then(...) // parameter 'fetchFromService' defaults to null
```